# Resolving incorrect DFS server when outside of network subnet

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, dfs

I have a number of IP networks in my organization. I am also running a single domain across my organization with DFS servers in two sites - London and Sydney.

My domain functional level is Server 2008.

Both DFS servers are Server 2008.

Let's say in Sydney I have the following networks:

```
10.152.0.0/24
10.32.0.0/24
10.56.0.0/24
```

DFS server IP here is `10.32.0.1`

and in London:

```
10.100.10.0/24
```

DFS server IP here is `100.10.100.1`

I have gone in to the Sites and Services AD snap in and added the subnets above under the correct sites.

It was my understanding that this would mean any DFS queries from 10.152.0.0 would go to the Sydney DFS server; however this is not the case.

I have been told that DFS doesn't care about Sites and Services and it just returns the server that is closest to the subnet you are in. E.g. if I was in London on a subnet `10.33.0.0/24` then DFS would resolve to Sydney because my subnet is closer to `10.32.0.0` than `10.100.10.0/24`. Is this true?

Does DFS not work this way or have I set up something incorrectly?

Comment: Hrm. I have a setup similar to yours, but the only time I have ever had a DFS seleted from a distant site is when the local DFS was offline. I was under the impression that it absolutely does use sites and services...

Comment: See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782417%28v=ws.10%29.aspx - the section about `How Site Discovery Works` and `How Target Selection Works`

Comment: Is there a typo in your London IP example? Not necessarily relevant but are your subnets truly 24-bit (i.e. 10.152.0.0/24 meaning 10.152.0.0 - 10.152.0.255) or 16-bit (10.152.0.0 - 10.152.255.255)?